# Allowing access to a base class member from a particular derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, member-access

In a project, I have a class hierarchy implementing a graph with levels of hierarchy (that is, a graph node can be a graph itself — think of it as an electronic circuit where a gate can actually be an integrated chip, for instance). Thus, I have some class `Base` derived into `Group` and `Leaf`, and the class `Base` has an attribute `ancestor`, which I would like to be able to set from a given method of `Group` (when adding a child), but not from anywhere else:

```
class Group;

class Base {
    private: // or protected?
        Group* ancestor;
};

class Group : public Base {
    private:
        void setAncestor(Base* child) {
            // Something like
            child->ancestor = this;
        }
};

class Leaf : public Base {
    // ...
};
```

What would be the "correct" way to achieve that? Usually, I would use `friend` methods, but it seems to me that this is impossible in this context, since I would have to declare friend `Group::setAncestor` in `Base`, which must be declared before. (Also note that those declarations are in different files in the real code.)

Comment: This doesn't work unless `ancestor` is public. `Group` can access protected members of *its own* base class. It can not access protected members through `Base` pointers, as these might be bases of some unrelated class, like `Leaf`.

Comment: You might make the whole class friend, i.e. `friend class Group;`.

Comment: You could use forward declaration and `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

data member Base::ancestor should have protected access.  That way it will be available to derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as protected in `Base`, and in the `Leaf` class and from anywhere else use private inheritance, so protected members will be private.

```
class Group;

class Base {
    protected:
        Group* ancestor;
};

class Group : public Base {
    private:
        void setAncestor(Base* newAncestor) {
            // Something like
            ancestor = newAncestor->ancestor;
        }
};

class Leaf : private Base {
    // ...
};
```

Note that I change the name from `child` to `newAncestor`.

So when you create a new child you can do something like this:

```
Base ancestor;
Group child;
child->setAncestor(&ancestor)
```

Comment: It won't have the same effect.

Comment: @O'Neil Off course `setAncestor()` has a different signature in my example. Just a suggestion. But I'm not sure if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Yes this is it. The point is to have `ancestor` to point to **another** instance. Not `this`.